# AbiFilters not working for library module

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have app project with library module dependency which is using so library (NDK). There are many so libraries for different ABIs. In my library project I have gradle looking like this:

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
      defaultPublishConfig debug // to build only debug variant
  }
buildTypes {
    debug {
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a"
        }
    }
```

The goal here is to make library module smaller (uploading to repository etc.) and have this only for development. AbiFilter is now working only for application project not for library. 
Am I missing something or abiFilter is not supported for library module? Thank you

Comment: any solution you find for this?

Comment: I am not using `defaultPublishConfig`, and with gradle plugin 3.0.1 same **android.buildTypes.debug.ndk.abiFilters** works well (Android Studio 3.0).

Comment: @warlock, did you find any solution?

Comment: @TanayMondal We're using a different approach. For example, we had 7 projects - 3 with apps and 4 only with library modules/dependencies used by those 3. We've picked our main app project and merged that 4 library projects into this one. Now we've more control about flavours, buildTypes etc. We're now still uploading to maven repo library aar for the rest of the app project. In the future we're planning to merge everything together in one big project and use feature "unload modules" from IDEA / Android Studio for faster gradle sync, clean etc. I hope this will help.

Comment: AS and gradle 3.6.1, issue is still there, abiFilters, like packagingOptions are not working in modules! Have to replicate the config over all apps depending on affected modules.